# WOL doesn't work when shutdown

Tags: windows-7, wake-on-lan

I've enabled WOL on shutdown function. I've disabled Energy Star from either Windows adapter settings and BIOS. I've enabled WOL on Magic Packet (also with broadcasting) and in power management tab all checkmarks are there. Still I am able to wake up the PC from sleep mode, but if I shut down it, no way to wake it up...

Mainboard is ASUS P5Q3, Windows 7 64 bit.

Pulling my hair off slowly...

I'm using direct LAN connection from Ubuntu server to that PC, through switch. LAN LED is on after shutdown. I have tried both ethernet ports, same result.

```
C:\>powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
Marvell Yukon 88E8001/8003/8010 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller
Marvell Yukon 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
```

Comment: @Michael - do you have a WOL cable connected from your NIC to the motherboard? All the correct settings in the world won't do a lick of good without that cable.

Comment: :) If I wouldn't have connected cable, how I would wake up from sleep mode?

Comment: go into the BIOS and make sure that **BOTH** LAN1 & LAN2 are enabled for WOL.

Comment: @PeSmith: there is no WOL setting in BIOS!

Comment: @person who upvoted first comment: `Motherboards with an embedded Ethernet controller which supports Wake-on-LAN do not need a cable.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found solution. Enabling `Power ON by PCI devices` option solved the issue. Hope I can get back my bounty points :)

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot.  You cannot award a bounty to yourself.

Comment: The option you mention can be set where? BIOS, Control Panel, ...?

Comment: @pablo c'mon man, I have this exact same problem with the Realtek LAN on my Gigabyte GA-Z68X-UD3H-B3. Where is the option located??

Comment: Usually, it's in the BIOS settings.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an onboard ethernet port.  In that case, you won't need a cable.  These days, most if not all new motherboards support WOL along with their built in NICs.  I'm curious why you turned off Energy Star.  Considering Energy Star requires compliant devices to have a WOL feature, I'd turn that back on.

Comment: Because I read in the docs that EnergyStar will turn off WOL for one of the LAN ports. But anyway, neither way works :(

Answer (score -6):

Well, it is "wake" on LAN and not "power up". I don't see how that would be possible. Your ethernet card is not powered when the machine is off, and it has no IP address, so I would be very interested if anyone has ever heard of this working.

And where, exactly, did you set "WOL on shutdown"?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8491172/wol1.png

Comment: Actually, WoL keeps ethernet cards powered while the machine is off, and has since the 1990s.